# ContentControl Template through Property

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a Usercontrol with a ControlTemplate DependencyProperty (named MyItemTemplate).

```
public ControlTemplate MyContentControl
        {
            get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(MyContentControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyContentControlProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentControlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyContentControl", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(MyScroll),
              new PropertyMetadata(new ControlTemplate()));
```

In the xaml of my UserControl I want to use the "MyItemTemplate" as a template for a ContentControl like that :

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl" Template="{Binding MyItemTemplate}" />
```

I know that the ***Template="{Binding MyItemTemplate}"*** is wrong, but I wonder how to do it...

Thanks

Comment: Should MyItemTemplate actually be MyContentControl or vice versa... the names in your question don't match up as I would expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeSource` binding to reference a custom `DependencyProperty` on your UserControl

```
<ContentControl Template="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, 
    Path=MyItemTemplate}" />
```

**Edit**

If you're working in Silverlight 4.0 or lower, which doesn't support `RelativeSource` bindings, then give your `UserControl` tag a Name and use an `ElementName` binding

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyUserControl" ...>
    <ContentControl Template="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=MyItemTemplate}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This solution is the best for WPF or Silverlight 5. However, in Silverlight 4, there's no support for ancestor `RelativeSource` so this won't work.

Comment: @PavelGatilov If you're working with Silverlight, you should be able to give your root UserControl a Name, and access it with an ElementName binding. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. Seems like my religion has made me forget this. :)

Comment: Superb!!! Thank you very much!  Thats exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks to everyone for helping me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have your template as a static resource (defined in your XAML somewhere).

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailedTemplate">

 <Border BorderBrush="Blue" Margin="3" Padding="3" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="Beige">

 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

 <Image Margin="10" Width="250" Height="200" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=ImageHref}">

 <Image.BitmapEffect>

 <DropShadowBitmapEffect />

 </Image.BitmapEffect>

 </Image>

 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">

 <TextBlock FontSize="25" Foreground="Goldenrod" Text="{Binding Path=ImageName}" />

 <Label Content="{Binding Path=ImageRating,Converter={StaticResource RatingConverter}}" />

 </StackPanel>

 </StackPanel>

 </Border>

</DataTemplate>



<DataTemplate x:Key="SimpleTemplate">

 <Border BorderBrush="Blue" Margin="3" Padding="3" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="Beige">

 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">

 <Image Margin="10" Width="250" Height="200" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=ImageHref}">

 <Image.BitmapEffect>

 <DropShadowBitmapEffect />

 </Image.BitmapEffect>

 </Image>

 </StackPanel>

 </Border>

</DataTemplate>
```

For example, in XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbResults" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="240" 

 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{StaticResource FavoriteImages}" 

 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SimpleTemplate}" />
```

Then in the code behind something like:

```
//pull the detailed template from resources, identified by the DetailedTemplate key

 DataTemplate detail = this.FindResource("DetailedTemplate") as DataTemplate;

 lbResults.ItemTemplate = detail;
```

and

```
//pull the summary template from resources, identified by the SimpleTemplate key

 DataTemplate summary = this.FindResource("SimpleTemplate") as DataTemplate;

 lbResults.ItemTemplate = summary;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the best answer is Rachel's, here are some alternatives.

If this logic is not critical, you'd better put the template into resources and get it using `StaticResource`:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template">
      ...
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource template}"/>
</UserControl>
```

---

If you still need to set it from the `UserControl`'s property, you may either define a change callback.
XAML:

```
<UserControl>
  <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
public ControlTemplate MyContentControl
{
  get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(MyContentControlProperty); }
  set { SetValue(MyContentControlProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentControlProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("MyContentControl", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(MyScroll), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMyContentControlChanged));

static void OnMyContentControlChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var userControl = (MyScroll)sender;

  userControl.contentControl.Template = e.NewValue as ControlTemplate;
}
```

---

And the last option is [using a Custom Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/03/22/tutorial-writing-a-templated-silverlight-2-control.aspx).
Code:

```
public class MyScroll : SomeParentControl
{
  public MyScroll()
  {
    this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyScroll);
  }

  public ControlTemplate MyContentControl
  {
    get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(MyContentControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyContentControlProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyContentControl", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(MyScroll), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

The template:

```
<!-- This is a template for what have been your UserControl -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type someNameSpaceAlias:MyScroll}">
  <!-- And this is the 'MyContentControl' -->
  <ContentControl Template="{TemplateBinding MyContentControl}"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```