# UserControl DataBinding

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

Most likely I am doing the databinding for my UserControl in a wrong manner, please point me to an error.

I have a UserControl decleared in XAML of my page view (view.xaml):

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,0" x:Name="ProgressBarPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <deusControls:BookProgressBar BookProgressValue="{Binding BookProgressInfo, Mode=OneWay}" Width="430" />
            </StackPanel>
```

The control itself is simply a wrapped listbox (myprogressbar.xaml):

```
<Grid x:Name="ProgressBarLayoutRoot">

        <ListBox x:Name="ProgressBarControl" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Bars, RelativeSource=this}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Height="15" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="{Binding Corner}" Width="{Binding Width}" Background="{Binding IsAchieved, Converter={StaticResource progressToColor}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

The `BookProgressValue` is registered in a control's code behind as a dependency property:

```
public BookProgressInfo BookProgressValue {
            get { return (BookProgressInfo)GetValue(BookProgressValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BookProgressValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BookProgressValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BookProgressValue", typeof(BookProgressInfo), typeof(BookProgressBar), 
            new PropertyMetadata(new BookProgressInfo(0), new PropertyChangedCallback(BookProgressValueChanged)));

        static void BookProgressValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bookProgressBar = (BookProgressBar)sender;

            var progressInfo = (BookProgressInfo) e.NewValue;

            if(progressInfo != null && progressInfo.Id != 0) 
                bookProgressBar.DataContext = new BookProgressBarViewModel(progressInfo, bookProgressBar.Width);
        }
```

The `BookProgressValue="{Binding BookProgressInfo, Mode=OneWay}"` should be binding to a `BookProgressInfo` property in the views view model.

The view model recieves a new data from the logic to put forward to UI as a value of `BookProgressInfo`property, and calls a `NotifyPropertyChanged("BookProgressInfo");`

At this point I am expecting my control to process `BookProgressValueChanged` event to update the control's own data context (basically to get an updated set of Bars that it binds to.) but the  `BookProgressValueChanged` is not raised after `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Main question is**:
What is the correct way of getting a view to have one DataContext, whereas a UserControl that is placed inside a view - to have it's own, base on a value to a dependecy property set through databinging?

Please let me know if the explanation of the question is unclear, I will improve. Thank you.

Comment: You should check the debug output window to look for binding exceptions. If it does not show anything - a sample project could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [ContentControl Template through Property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8343237/795861)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should add to root grid this line:

```
<Grid x:Name="ProgressBarLayoutRoot" 
      DataContext="{Binding ElementName=userControl, BookProgressValue}"
```

And also add name to your UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `Binding` for the `ListBox.ItemsSource` is wrong: there's no 'RelativeSource=this' in Silverlight.

Several options on doing this correctly are given in [ContentControl Template through Property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8343237/795861). Please, have a look.